# Is this counterexample of $\mathbb{P}( | X | \ge c) \le \frac{\text{Var}[X]}{c^2}$ correct?

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, binomial-distribution

> Let $X$ be a real valued random variable. Does $\mathbb{P}( | X | \ge c) \le \frac{\text{Var}[X]}{c^2}$ hold for $c > 0$?

**My counterexample:**

Let $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,0)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then we have $\text{Var}[X] = 0$ but (since $|X| = X$)
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[X \ge 2]
& = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \le 1) + \mathbb{P}(X = 1)
= 1 - \left(\sum_{k = 0}^{1} \binom{n}{k} 0^k 1^{1 - k}\right) + \binom{n}{k} 0^k 1^{1 - k} \\
& = 1 - 0 + 0
= 1 > 0.
\end{align*}

Is this correct? Is there an easier counterexample?

---

**Edit 1:**
Since the above counterexample is wrong, here's a second idea.

Let $X \in \text{Ber}(1)$.
Then we have $\textsf{V}[X] = 1 \cdot (1 - 1) = 0$ but since $\mathbb{P}(X = k) \ne 0$ only for $k = 1$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \ge 1)
= \mathbb{P}(X = 1) + \mathbb{P}(X = 0)
= 1  + 0 > 0.
$$

Comment: Here $P(X\geq2)=1-P(X\leq1)$ so not $P(X\geq2)=1-P(X\leq1)+P(X=1)$. Furher $\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{1} \binom{1}{k} 0^k 1^{1 - k}\right)=\binom100^01^1+\binom110^11^0=1\cdot1\cdot1+1\cdot0\cdot1=1+0=1$.

Comment: $\text{Var}[X] = 0$ ???

Comment: Sorry, I missed the $p=0$. Of course $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,0)$ just says $X=0$, so your conclusion that $P(X\ge2)=1$ is absurd.

Comment: You're right, I missed the $0^0 = 1$ term. Therefore, we have, as one espects $\mathbb{P}[X \ge 2] = 0$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Hint regarding a correct counterexample: If $\Bbb EX=0$ the inequality is true.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So my new counterexample is correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks right. I cannot fathom why you don't just say $X=1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Do you think I should delete the question now that my problems have been resolved? Otherwise I would welcome you post what you commented as an answer so this question doesn't look unanswered.